# Jquery Validation dynamically add rules for each input once form generated

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

I have php dynamically creating a form, and it being loaded with Ajax. Im then using jQuery Validation to check the form, but as I do not know the names of the inputs in advance, I need to add the rules after the form is loaded and before a user submits the form.

I've tried the following, but it attempts to submit the form on the first click, and then check the rules on the second.

```
$("#readingForm").validate({
        invalidHandler: function () { //display error alert on form submit              
            EMPGlobal.showAlert('', '', 'danger', 'There was an error' , '', '', '', 'warning');
        },
        submitHandler: function (){     
            $('#readingForm .meter-val').each(function(){
                $(this).rules( "add", {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
                    minlength: 2
                });
            });
            $('#readingForm .insert-val').each(function(){
                $(this).rules( "add", {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    date: true
                });
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: 'include/pages/readings.php?',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    EMPGlobal.showAlert('', '', 'success', message, '', '', '', 'success', jqXHR.status);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    returnMes = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                    message = 'A ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + errorThrown + ' error occured. <br /> <i>Message Details: ' + returnMes + '</i>';
                    EMPGlobal.showAlert('', '', 'danger', message, '', '', '', 'warning', jqXHR.status);
                },
            });
        }
    });
```

Help on this one would be really appreciated, I've been going round in circles with this one for hours.

Comment: where did you place this code.. is in inside a submit/click event handler

Comment: You have added the rules inside the submit handler, that's why rules are applied after submitting the form. Try to put the rules in before submitting the form(In form validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
$("#readingForm").validate({
    invalidHandler: function () { //display error alert on form submit              
        EMPGlobal.showAlert('', '', 'danger', 'There was an error' , '', '', '', 'warning');
    },
    submitHandler: function (){     
        $('#readingForm .meter-val').each(function(){
            $(this).rules( "add", {
               ///
            });
        });
        $('#readingForm .insert-val').each(function(){
            $(this).rules( "add", {
                ///
            });
        });
        $.ajax({
            ///
        });
    }
});
```

> it attempts to submit the form on the first click, and then check the rules on the second.

While you should **not** put the `.rules()` method anywhere inside of the `.validate()` method, it certainly makes no sense inside of the `submitHandler`.  Since the `submitHandler` only fires when the form is valid, it's too late to be adding/evaluating any new rules... this is why you have to click twice.

> I do not know the names of the inputs in advance, I need to add the rules after the form is loaded and before a user submits the form.

1. Call `.validate()` as soon as the form itself is created.  This is what initializes the plugin.   Do it *one time* inside the DOM ready handler if the form exists when the page loads.  Otherwise, do it *one time* immediately after the form is loaded/created.
2. Call the `.rules()` method as soon as the form's inputs are created.  Do it **outside** of the `.validate()` method.  If the input elements are created at the same time as the form, simply call the `.rules()` method *after* you call `.validate()`.

```
// Call .validate() ONCE, after form is created.

$("#readingForm").validate({
    invalidHandler: function () { //display error alert on form submit              
        EMPGlobal.showAlert('', '', 'danger', 'There was an error' , '', '', '', 'warning');
    },
    submitHandler: function (){     
        $.ajax({
            url: 'include/pages/readings.php?',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                EMPGlobal.showAlert('', '', 'success', message, '', '', '', 'success', jqXHR.status);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                returnMes = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                message = 'A ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + errorThrown + ' error occured. <br /> <i>Message Details: ' + returnMes + '</i>';
                EMPGlobal.showAlert('', '', 'danger', message, '', '', '', 'warning', jqXHR.status);
            },
        });
    }
});

// Call .rules() ONCE, after relevant elements are created AND after .validate().

$('#readingForm .meter-val').each(function(){
    $(this).rules( "add", {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        minlength: 2
    });
});
$('#readingForm .insert-val').each(function(){
    $(this).rules( "add", {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        date: true
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, that has resolved that problem, however, now my additional method for verifying dates fails.

Comment: Managed to get around needing the additional method by using dateITA